# Dockerfile to start PHP Container with mysqli and a2enmod rewrite not working

Tags: php, apache, docker

I'm trying to start a container based on a dockerfile. it shoud have mysqli and a2enmod.

My Dockerfile is

```
FROM php:7.1-apache
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli && a2enmod rewrite && service apache2 restart
```

but the a2enmod is not enablad before start. When I Attach to the container bash I got that a2enmod was not enabled

```
$ a2enmod rewrite
Enabling module rewrite.
To activate the new configuration, you need to run: service apache2 restart
$ a2enmod rewrite
Module rewrite already enabled
```

What am  I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe specify the full path to the a2enmod script.

Comment: It seams that the module ist not enabled by default in the containers. A container is built from the image on start. I'm not very familiar with docker. It seems you need to learn how to change the docker image. (The image is like a template for container instances.)

Comment: Did you rebuild your docker image? How do you run the container? Why do you run `service apache2 restart` in Dockerfile?

Comment: @AlexKarshin a restart of apache2 is required after enabling modules. I guess the commands in the docker file are executed in some too early state when not available yet.

Comment: As ryantxr suggests, using full paths might work. Paths to some executables (`$PATH`) might only be available in interactive shells.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone please read how Docker works. I know apache restart is required, but apache is running in container, not during build time :-/

Comment: In general you should assume commands like `service` just don't work in Docker.  As @AlexKarshin is suggesting, in this case I think you can just remove the `service apache2 restart` part of the line: Apache isn't running during the build phase and running `docker run` will start it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested by [Alex Karshin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3324556/alex-karshin), there was 2 problems.

1. I need to rebuild the docker image.
2. I don't need to restart the apache service because apache was not running during container initialization.

Fixing those issues solved my problem.

Comment: Yep. I forgot to rebuild the image. Dumb me. Thanks stranger 